# params[:date] prints date as a number

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, date, format, parameters

I have a form which does a GET request through remote to `user_path(@user)` in a file called index.html.erb. In my show.js.erb I have a function which searches for the records within the start and end date.
When I pass the date arguments as `1.week.ago.to_date` and `Date.today` (and in my function I have a range like `range=start..stop` where `start` is the start date and `stop` is the stop date) the method works fine and my div in index.html.erb is updated.
But when I pass the attributes through the date picker jquery in my form the method gives me a bad range error.
I can see the dates in the parameters' get request in the proper format, but when I do a print of the parameter through show.js.erb it prints something like 0.00329843434345245 (I assume it is date in milliseconds). When I try to convert the `params[:from_date].to_i` the method gives me an error saying unable to convert string to a number. I just need to pass the params as proper date attributes to the method so that it fetches me the records properly.
Please reply if anybody knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your timestamp (the date in seconds since 01/01/1970)
is wrong , it should never contain dots
if you try on a JS console

```
var now =  new Date().getTime()
```

you should see something like : 1371476912800
the problem must be either the way you send the date to the server :

in this case Try to send the timestamp of your date to the server or be sure that th

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
$.post("/page/get-date", { from_date: now.toString() });
```

Or the fact that you can't convert a date represented as a string to an integer
but rather pass the string to the constructor of the rails Date object and then convert to a timestamp.
hope that helped

Ajios !

Comment: I dono how it got solved! I just logged off and left if for the weekend  and when I logged in on Monday voila! it worked the way it should. I guess it was some wired cache. Thanks for replying.